# process running after kill/uninstall

Tags: android, cpu-usage

I'm working on an app with many libraries included. Later I noticed a couple of occasions where the app process was still draining CPU after closing the app.

I killed the process first, but it kept going. I uninstalled the app - and it was still there! (using "Show CPU usage" option from developer options).

I am pretty sure we are not doing anything that advanced in the app and the problem is in some of the libraries. Do you know how you can achieve such 'virus-y' effect?

Thanks,
Dan

EDIT: after uninstallation of the xxxx app, (I ran adb uninstall com.xxxx.android)this is what I get:

adb shell top -m 10

> PID PR CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
>
> 13309  0  77% Z     8      0K      0K     u0_a57   m.xxxx.android

There is a weird thing here: the app is com.xxxx.android, and what is see is only "m". So now I know it continues to drain battery after uninstallation (or at least process connected with this). So my question is : how is this possible?

Comment: I think that you are putting too much faith in your interpretation of what you are seeing in "Show CPU usage".

Comment: @CommonsWare, what do you mean in my interpretation? I see the the package name as name of the process that is using the CPU. The phone is hot and the battery dropped for 30 minutes to 20%. Battery settings is showing my application as the main reason for the battery drain (41%).

Comment: "what do you mean in my interpretation?" -- you are assuming that the list of processes is a list of currently-running processes.

Comment: I'm talking about the feature "Show CPU usage" in the developer options. It is usually showing currently running processes, and this one is actually showing activity on the CPU side. I may be wrong, but I don't see how this can show so inaccurate information.

Comment: "It is usually showing currently running processes" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? Did you compare the list of processes with anything else, like DDMS, **`top`**, or the list of running processes shown in Settings? It could very well be showing the names of processes that contributed to the historical Linux CPU load values. Uninstalling an app kills its process, removes its Linux uid, etc. I'm not saying that you're wrong, but you'd need a whole lot more evidence that uninstall is broken than just "Show CPU usage".

Comment: Hmmm, what do you suggest is still draining the battery after uninstalling the application? It shows only this process that is using the CPU, the phone is still staying warm. There are not other apps causing the same symptoms. I thought it is obvious that it is still this process that is causing the problem.

Comment: It'll take time and chance to reproduce this again, since it is happening very rarely, but next time I'll try "top", although it seems logical that "Show CPU Usage" is actually using the "top -o cpu" results.

Comment: "Hmmm, what do you suggest is still draining the battery after uninstalling the application?" -- I have no way to know, as I have no idea what your app even does. My point is that you are effectively claiming that whatever you did to kill the process (DDMS?) is broken, and that uninstalling an app is broken. That's entirely possible, but serious claims require serious evidence, and the actual behavior of the process list of "Show CPU usage" is undocumented.

Comment: I killed the process as a user (4.x swipe). This is usually enough for  it to disappear from "Show CPU usage".
When I saw it didn't, I uninstall the app (adb uninstall ...)
Since I've seen this one more time after adding a specific library and this was the second time for 1 month, I decided to seek help here.
If I experience this again (not likely soon) I'll add more information.

Comment: "I killed the process as a user (4.x swipe)" -- that does not necessarily terminate the process. The precise behavior depends a bit on Android version. Usually, it will terminate the process unless there is a `startForeground()` service running in that process. DDMS is a more solid way to ensure that a process is terminated. And, of course, uninstalling the app should get rid of everything.

Comment: Well, yes, this is what I was thinking at the time, that we (not only the library) may be doing something wrong and looping in the background with a service or something else. Then I tried uninstalling, just to stop the battery drain, but that didn't help. So I was wondering how that is even possible.

Comment: The library I suspect requires <android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"

Comment: @CommonsWare, happened again, here is the results from adb shell top.

Comment: That is inexplicable. What version of Android, and what device/emulator are you experiencing this on?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your thirdpart libraries have a broadcast receiver running?